# So what is the story with 4 quotes?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, quotes

I was experimenting in the python shell with the type() operator. I noted that:

```
type('''' string '''')
```

returns an error which is trouble scanning the string

yet:

```
type(''''' string ''''')
```

works fine and responds that a string was found.

What is going on? does it have to do with the fact that `type('''' string '''')` is interpreted as `type("" "" string "" "")` and therefore a meaningless concatenation of empty strings and an undefined variable?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a dup of another question, but I can't find it, and I think it had just one answer by Martijn Pieters and his answer here is even better than last time, so… I'm giving up searching.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are ending a string with 3 quotes, plus *one* extra. This works:

```
>>> ''''string'''
"'string"
```

In other words, Python sees 3 quotes, then the string ends at the *next* 3 quotes. Anything that follows after that is *not* part of the string anymore.

Python also concatenates strings that are placed one after the other:

```
>>> 'foo' 'bar'
'foobar'
```

so `'''''string'''''` means `'''''string''' + ''` really; the first string starts right after the opening 3 quotes until it finds 3 closing quotes. Those three closing quotes are then followed by two more quotes forming a separate but empty string:

```
>>> '''''string'''
"''string"
>>> '''''string'''''
"''string"
>>> '''''string'''' - extra extra! -'
"''string - extra extra! -"
```

Moral of the story: Python only supports triple or single quoting. Anything deviating from that can only lead to pain.

Comment: how does one express  "'string'" ?

Comment: ^that consists of a " next to a single '

Comment: @frogeyedpeas: Use escapes (`"\"'string'\""`) or triple single quotes (`'''"'string'"'''`).

Answer (score 0):

Your supposition seems to be correct, given the following:

```
a = '''' string ''''
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    a = '''' string ''''
                       ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

As Martijn says in his answer, Python is trying to concatenate adjacent strings, and fails when it doesn't find the ending `'`.